# Unable to upload more than 30 seconds videos to Facebook from iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook, video

I have searched different questions like

[Unable to upload large videos to Facebook from iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14947776/2160239)

[upload video to facebook using facebook sdk 3.1 on ios 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12861615)

and many more. None of the resources available is able to help with this. I am successfully able to upload smaller videos (e.g. 3-4 seconds videos).

I am using Facebook sdk 3.2. The resource pointed to by facebook is following, which does not use facebook SDK. Is video upload broken in facebook 3.2 sdk?

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/08/04/how-to--use-the-graph-api-to-upload-a-video--ios/

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Since you can upload smaller videos, the issue may not be on the SDK side. Can you check your video size and if you're hitting video upload limits? One way to check the limit is to use the Graph API Explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and do a GET on me?fields=id,video_upload_limits

Comment: Never had this problem earlier with many applications. Is this something new enforcement from Facebook?

Comment: Just verified that it is not related to the video upload limit as it is
 "video_upload_limits": {
    "length": 600,
    "size": 104857600
  } 
and the request still fails. Even the Video Upload Test project (from facebook) behaves in similar way. Its pretty erratic and the error returned on the failure is "Failed with error: The request timed out."

Comment: You want to say that there is no limit on uploading the video on facebook from app

Comment: Amit are you still seeing the error?

Comment: I have a fix here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17927767/upload-large-videos-to-facebook-with-ios-sdk/17927784#17927784, although 600 MB might even be too big for a memory mapped file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is fixed in latest update from FB SDK.

Comment: Anyone know the max video size? I always get unknown error on a 4 minute video...

Comment: I have a fix here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17927767/upload-large-videos-to-facebook-with-ios-sdk/17927784#17927784